# any tutorial to set up nginx+ uwsgi to serve pylons apps?

Tags: nginx, tutorial, uwsgi, pylons

Currently I am using [nginx to reverse proxy paster](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Running+Pylons+with+NGINX), to server [Mediacore](http://getmediacore.com/docs/) (a Pylons app). However, this configuration fails when I try to submit a video. I particualrly try to avoid fat  appache, which is the official Mediacore recommendation. In a famous "[benchmark of python webservers](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers)"  I've seen that uwsgi has amazing performance but it is rather newcommer. So I could not find any good tutorial for it which is both comprehensive and noob-friendly. So I I appreciate if you could refere me to such guide to set up any of the  high-performance python webservers. Thanks in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying pylons apps is very easy on uWSGI.
Simply add this section to your deployment.ini

[uwsgi]
master = 1
processes = 4
socket = :3031
home = `<venv>`

Substitute `<venv>` with the full path of your virtualenv and eventually change the socket port
to whatever you want/need

Now go to nginx.conf and modify it to something like this:

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
}

Obviously set the uwsgi_pass to the right port of the uWSGI socket

Now start uwsgi

uwsgi --ini-paste `<path>`

Where `<path>` is the full path of the deployment.ini file

If you are on a big server you can increse the number of processes too

Comment: When I run 'uwsgi --ini-paste /path/to/deployment.ini' I get this:
'uwsgi: unrecognized option '--ini-paste'. And this is while I've installed uwsgi using 'pip install http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz'

Comment: That is strange, could it be that you have another (old) binary of uwsgi in your path ? Try to 'pip install' and run it directly from your virtualenv

Comment: I did 'pip install uwsgi' on my virtualenv and then run the command 'uwsgi --ini-paste deployment.ini' while I was on my project root and in the virtualenv, but still get the same error :(

Comment: what 'uwsgi --version' reports ? if you use --ini instead on --ini-paste does the stack loads ?

Comment: Are you using pypy?   I had this 'uwsgi: unrecognized option '--ini-paste' problem too, and on pypy, you need `--pypy-paste` instead